# Grouping labels and hyperlink button together in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, hyperlink, alignment, label

I have a label and a hyperlink button in silverlight and I would like to group them together so that the alignment is done on that group rather that having to align two different elements. Any idea of how this could be done please?

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,177,6"/>

<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="http://www.mywebsite.mt/" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,132,6">
        <TextBlock Text="myWebsite" Foreground="Black" TextDecorations="Underline" />
</HyperlinkButton>
```

I want these a group, so I could only use 1 margin alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really need to use `Margin` like that, but since it looks they would just sit on top of one another you could of course use something like `StackPanel` to accomplish it.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,6">
   <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
   <HyperlinkButton Content="myWebsite" Foreground="Black" NavigateUri="http://www.mywebsite.mt/"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Hope this helps.